# java rmic not working

Tags: java, rmi, rmic

i am learning rmi for practice from a book in book following code but rmic not working

```
package chapter4.printers;

import chapter4.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;

public class NullPrinter extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Printer {

    private PrintWriter log;
    public NullPrinter(OutputStream log) throws RemoteException {
        this.log = new PrintWriter(log);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean printerAvailable() throws RemoteException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean printDocument(DocumentDescription document) throws RemoteException, PrinterException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (null == log) {
            throw new NoLogException();
        }

        if (null == document) {
            throw new NoDocumentException();
        }
        log.println("Printed file");
        log.flush();
        if(log.checkError()) {
            throw new CantWriteToLogException();
        }
        return true;
    }

    private class NoLogException extends PrinterException {
        public NoLogException() {
            super(0, "Null printer failure. No log to record" +
        " print request.");
        }
    }

    private class NoDocumentException extends PrinterException {
        public NoDocumentException() {
            super(0, "Null printer failure. No document receive" +
                    " as part of print request.");
        }
    }

    private class CantWriteToLogException extends PrinterException {
        public CantWriteToLogException() {
            super(0, "Null printer failure. Attempt to record " +
        "print request to log failed.");
        }
    }
}


package chapter4.applications;

import chapter4.printers.*;
import chapter4.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;
public class SimpleServer implements NetworkConstants {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File logFile = new File("serverLogFile");
            OutputStream outputStream = 
                    new FileOutputStream(logFile);
            Printer printer =
                    new NullPrinter(outputStream);

              Naming.rebind(DEFAULT_PRINTER_NAME, printer);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Messages:

> Warning: generation and use of skeletons and static stubs for JRMP
>   is deprecated. Skeletons are unnecessary, and static stubs have
>   been superseded by dynamically generated stubs. Users are
>   encouraged to migrate away from using rmic to generate skeletons and static
>   stubs. See the documentation for java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.
>
> error: Class printers.NullPrinter not found.
>   1 error

but the nullprinter.class is there in folder printer

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
package chapter4.printers;
```

> > Class printers.NullPrinter not found. 1 error
>
> but the nullprinter.class is there in folder printer

But it should be in `chapter4/printers`, and its name is not `printers.NullPrinter`. It is `chapter4.printers.NullPrinter`. Which also means you should be running `rmic` from the directory *containing* the `chapter4` directory:

```
rmic chapter4.printers.NullPrinter
```

Comment: i don't understand can make me more clear what should i write in argument                                                                                                  
 my path to NullPrinter.class file is E:\eclipseneonworkspace\rmi\bin\chapter4\printers

Comment: Your path should be `E:\eclipseonworkspace\rmi\bin`, which is the one that contains `chapter4`, as I already said, and I have already given you what to write in the argument. All this seems pretty clear already.

Comment: can you tell me where to set the path in eclipse for rmic and E:\eclipseonworkspace\rmi\bin in old book it is not written i have read it but it is not there i got stuck in eclipse settings